# AWS IAM Policy condition statement logical OR operator

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecr

I have a simple IAM policy with two conditions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPush",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:username": [
            "user01",
            "marketing"
          ]
        },
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:sourceArn": [
            "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:987654321:function:*",
            "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:481275139:function:*",
            "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:428385139:function:*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to grant an entity permissions `ecr:*` if ONE of the two conditions are met, either their are `user01` / `marketing` or a lambda function from another account is requesting the grant.

I have tried the policy before but it seems like the two conditions must be met at the same time in order to work.

Note: This policy is attached to an ECR repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your policy statement has multiple condition operators, so the condition operators are evaluated using a logical AND.

Your `aws:username` context key has multiple values, so those values are evaluated using a logical OR. Ditto for the `aws:sourceArn` context key.

Here is a visualization of IAM policy evaluation of conditions.

[image]

If you want either condition (OR) rather than both conditions (AND) use two statements, like so:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPushUser",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:username": [
            "user01",
            "marketing"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPushLambda",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com",
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:sourceArn": [
            "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:987654321:function:*",
            "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:481275139:function:*",
            "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:428385139:function:*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```